# Will object created with Object.create inherit from the prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Consider the following code:

```
var oNew = Object.create(MyConstructor.prototype);
```

Say, `MyConstructor` has "own" data members defined inside the constructor. Will `oNew` inherit those data members? Will `oNew` inherit all the `MyConstructor.prototype` methods? Also, `MyConstructor.prototype` may itself in inherit from an object, say `new f()`.

Comment: some **actual** code would help describe your *problem* better

Comment: I think that the correct way it would be first create the object: `var oNew = function() {};` and right after apply the inheritance: `oNew.prototype = Object.create(MyConstructor.prototype);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say, `MyConstructor` has "own" data members defined inside the constructor. Will oNew inherit those data members?

No, it will not; the prototype's `constructor` function is separate from the prototype intentionally. One of the main benefits of `Object.create` is that it allows you to separate the process of object *creation* from that of object *instantiation* (calling a constructor using `new` does combines the two).

> Will oNew inherit all the `MyConstructor.prototype` methods?

Yes, properties assigned directly to the prototype are inherited even when using `Object.create`.

### **Demo**

```js
function MyConstructor () {
  this.ownProperty = 'value'
}

MyConstructor.prototype.inheritedProperty = 'value'

var createdObject = Object.create(MyConstructor.prototype)

console.log(createdObject)
console.log('inheritedProperty' in createdObject) //=> true
console.log('ownProperty' in createdObject) //=> false


var constructedObject = new MyConstructor()

console.log(constructedObject)
console.log('inheritedProperty' in constructedObject) //=> true
console.log('ownProperty' in constructedObject) //=> true
```